# Removing entries from Pandas DF beginning with letter and two numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I am curious as to how to remove string entries from a Pandas DF beginning with a letter and two numbers and replacing with NaN.

```
A        B         C          D
Apple    Pear      N45 82f    John 
Cat      P48 hH2   Mary       Sponge 
Hat      P67 De1   Bed        S90 GGGF
```

I would like to replace all entries across the DF beginning with a letter and two numbers with NaN.

I have tried something along the lines of

```
for columns in df.columns[1:]:
    for i in columns: 
        if i[0].isalpha() and i[1].isdigit and i.[2].isdigit():
            i.replace(i,None)
```

Unfortunately this not seem to function. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.mask(df.apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{2}')))
```

Output:

```
       A     B     C       D
0  Apple  Pear   NaN    John
1    Cat   NaN  Mary  Sponge
2    Hat   NaN   Bed     NaN
```

I like @coldspeed's stack too:

```
df[~df.stack().str.contains('[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{2}').unstack()]
```

Output:

```
       A     B     C       D
0  Apple  Pear   NaN    John
1    Cat   NaN  Mary  Sponge
2    Hat   NaN   Bed     NaN
```

Comment: This seems to work fine. Although one question. I do have some entries which begin with 1, 2, or 3 numbers followed by some letters (addresses) which I would like to keep. Is there a way to remove only entries beginning with a letter followed by 2 numbers? i.e. these are postcodes.

Edit: nevermind, your original way, and not @coldspeed's method does this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `stack` and `str.extract` with a pattern that *does not match* what you want to match (this way, they're replaced with NaNs).

```
df.stack().str.extract(r'(^[^a-z]\D{2}.*)').unstack()[0]

       A     B     C       D
0  Apple  Pear   NaN    John
1    Cat   NaN  Mary  Sponge
2    Hat   NaN   Bed     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I never full got up to speed with regular expressions. I would have never thought of this solution. It runs fine, although my columns are object type which I just noticed. I will try convert to str and run this. Thank you.